# How to select the most recent record, and then query it based of its values?

Tags: postgresql, time

I'm try to complete a query and pull the results into a table on PHP.

The query works however, it does not complete the most necessary part.

I need the query to be able to pick the most recent record, THEN check whether the RSSI is GREATER than -60, however its picking the most record record WHERE the RSSI is GREATER than -60.

For instance, if a user is 'present' that means their RSSI is less than -60, however if they move further away, and their RSSI changes to -70 then they should not be found in this query, however the query is picking the most recent instance of where they are greater than -60.

Below is my code:

```
SELECT studentDetails.firstName,studentDetails.lastName,studentDetails.pictureLocation,probeSniffer.mac_address,probeSniffer.time_Stamp,probeSniffer.rssi,MAX(probeSniffer.time_Stamp) FROM probeSniffer
                Inner join studentDetails
                On probeSniffer.mac_address=studentDetails.mac_address
                WHERE probeSniffer.mac_address
                in 
                (SELECT probeSniffer.mac_address FROM probeSniffer WHERE probeSniffer.time_Stamp between (time('now', 'localtime', studentDetails.time_Range)) AND time('now', 'localtime'))
                AND probeSniffer.mac_address in (SELECT probeSniffer.mac_address FROM probeSniffer WHERE probeSniffer.rssi <= 0 AND probeSniffer.rssi >= studentDetails.rssi_range order by probeSniffer.time_Stamp desc)
                GROUP BY probeSniffer.mac_address
```

This picks up the user, however if they move away, they are still picked up.

Any ideas?

CREATE TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE probeSniffer (logID INTEGER UNIQUE, mac_address TEXT,vendor TEXT,ssid TEXT, date_Stamp TEXT, time_Stamp TEXT, rssi NUMERIC, bssid TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(logID))
CREATE TABLE `studentDetails` ( studentID INTEGER UNIQUE, firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, mac_address TEXT, pictureLocation TEXT, rssi_range TEXT, time_Range TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(studentID) )
```

RESULT:

```
"Jason" "Mills" "images/man.png"    "00:04:4b"  "15:05:16"  "-70"   "15:05:16"

"Andy"  "Harvey"    "images/man.png"    "8c:f5:a3"  "15:02:22"  "-79"   "15:02:22"
```

EXPECTED RESULT:
None as they're most recent RSSI values are less than -60, however its is picking up the most recent record of when they were greater than -60.

For example if you change the query a little bit:

```
SELECT studentDetails.firstName,studentDetails.lastName,studentDetails.pictureLocation,probeSniffer.mac_address,probeSniffer.time_Stamp,probeSniffer.rssi,MAX(probeSniffer.time_Stamp) FROM probeSniffer
                    Inner join studentDetails
                    On probeSniffer.mac_address=studentDetails.mac_address
                    WHERE 
                    probeSniffer.time_Stamp between (time('now', 'localtime', studentDetails.time_Range)) AND time('now', 'localtime')
                    AND probeSniffer.rssi >= studentDetails.rssi_range
                    GROUP BY probeSniffer.mac_address
```

The result is:

```
"Jason" "Mills" "images/man.png"    "00:04:4b"  "15:05:42"  "-60"   "15:05:42"

"Andy"  "Harvey"    "images/man.png"    "8c:f5:a3"  "14:43:13"  "-49"   "14:43:13"
```

INSERT INTO:

```
INSERT INTO `studentDetails`(`studentID`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`mac_address`,`pictureLocation`,`rssi_range`,`time_Range`) VALUES (NULL,Andy,Harvey,8c:f5:a3,images/man.png,-60,-60 minutes);
INSERT INTO `studentDetails`(`studentID`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`mac_address`,`pictureLocation`,`rssi_range`,`time_Range`) VALUES (NULL,Jason,Mills,8c:f5:a4,images/man.png,-60,-60 minutes);
INSERT INTO `studentDetails`(`studentID`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`mac_address`,`pictureLocation`,`rssi_range`,`time_Range`) VALUES (NULL,Bob,Harris,8c:f5:a5,images/man.png,-60,-60 minutes);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add: The `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables. Sample data for the tables as `INSERT INTO` statements. The expected result with the given sample data.

Comment: Will do give me a second.

Comment: ...,and please note that most people don't like horizonlal scrolling ...

Comment: What's with all those back ticks? They rather indicate MySQL not Postgres. And that can make a great difference here. If it is for MySQL please state the version of MySQL and change the tag. Otherwise explain why there are these back ticks.

Comment: SQLite automatically adds them